# How to merge two custom reports in different properties together in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have two different properties, one property is for historical data (e.g. from 01/01/2016 - 09/25/2016), while another one includes data from 09/26/2016-present.  I want to create a custom report, which includes the data from 01/01/2016 - present.

I have tried to use Views option -> 2 views selected when  I am building the custom report. However, it creates one view in each property, which has data for separate date ranges. Is it possible to merge these two views in different properties together to get data from 01/01/2016 - present?

Comment: do you have biq query access for both of the propertes ?

Comment: No, you can't make a Custom Report in Google Analytics that reports data from two different Properties, and you can't merge the Properties either.

Comment: @MagnusKragelund  I am going to export them as CSV files. then merge them there. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GA UI its not Possible, but there is good workaround.

***Using GA API via Google Sheets aka Google Analytics automation script***

You can use the Google Analytics API and Google Apps Script to access your Google Analytics data from Google Sheets. This is powerful because it allows you to utilize all the great features of Google Sheets with your analytics data, such as easy sharing, collaboration, charting and visualization tools. ([**Study here**](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/reporting-apps-script))

- Create a sheet, pull data from property 1.
- In sheet 2 pull data from property 2.
- Merge the data in Sheet 3.

Fairly easy and manageable.

---

***Big Query***

If you have access to Big Query account for each property, then just write a query taking data from two different data sets for the desired range using TABLE_DATE_RANGE. (**[Study Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql)**)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. we don't use Big Query in my corporation, so I am going to try the Google Sheet one. Thank again :)

Comment: @AkiraKaneshiro nps let me know if that works for you.  Upvote/Accept the answer if it helped. :)

Comment: It helped! sorry I cannot upvote it since I don't have enough reputations :( sorry

Comment: @AkiraKaneshiro You can accept the answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers